# Usb Midi cable on iOS simulator

Tags: objective-c, xcode4.5, coremidi

I would like to test some code that uses midi functions on iOS simulator from xcode.
Is there a way to let iOS simulator see the USB MIDI PORT connected to the Computer?
Xcode 4.6 - iOS simulator 6.1

thans to everybody

Answer (score 1):

No. The *External Accessory* framwork does not work in the iOS simulator according to [Apple](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/IDEs/Conceptual/iOS_Simulator_Guide/TestingontheiOSSimulator/TestingontheiOSSimulator.html)